# How to get data from another table from database?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I want to get data from table `role_users` , column `role_id` . For the moment, I have this in my controller :

```
$data['contact_users'] = DB::table('contacts')
                    ->join('users' , 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.contact_id')
                    ->join('industries' , 'industries.id', '=', 'users.industry_id')
                    ->join('countries' , 'countries.id', '=', 'users.country_id')
                    ->join('organization_types' , 'organization_types.id', '=', 'users.organization_type_id')
                    ->select('users.*','industries.industry','countries.country','organization_types.organization_type')
                    ->where('contacts.contact_id','!=',$id)
                    ->where('users.deleted_at','=',NULL)
                    ->whereIn('contacts.user_id', $contact_id)
                    ->whereNotIn('contacts.contact_id', $contact_id)
                    ->whereNotIn('contacts.contact_id', $inviter_id)
                    ->groupBy('contact_id')
                    ->take(4)
                    ->get();
```

I'm using it in view  with this code :

```
{{$contact->industry_id}} or {{$contact->country_id}}
```

I need to use something like this.

```
{{$contact->role_id}}
```

which is working for every user.But I need to get data from `role_users`,column `role_id`.I don't know how to use `->join()` and I need it so much.Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using Eloquent relationships to handle this? You could probably greatly simplify things by doing so. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added one extra join and one select field at the end,

```
$data['contact_users'] = DB::table('contacts')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.contact_id')
    ->join('industries', 'industries.id', '=', 'users.industry_id')
    ->join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'users.country_id')
    ->join('organization_types', 'organization_types.id', '=', 'users.organization_type_id')
    ->join("role_users", "role_users.user_id","=","users.id")
    ->select('users.*', 'industries.industry', 'countries.country', 'organization_types.organization_type', "role_users.role_id")
    ->where('contacts.contact_id', '!=', $id)
    ->where('users.deleted_at', '=', null)
    ->whereIn('contacts.user_id', $contact_id)
    ->whereNotIn('contacts.contact_id', $contact_id)
    ->whereNotIn('contacts.contact_id', $inviter_id)
    ->groupBy('contact_id')
    ->take(4)
    ->get();
```

Comment: I got this error : `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'wscomDev.user_roles' doesn't exist `

Comment: use role_users.role_id in place of user_roles.role_id

Comment: @RahulRai If *But I need to get data from role_users,column role_id* this is OP's question how can users table have role_id to join?

Comment: Welcome! Please don't forget to accept answer! :) Thanks.